# How to access a HSTORE column using PostgreSQL C library (libpq)?

Tags: postgresql, hstore, libpq

I cannot find any documentation regarding HSTORE data access using the C library. Currently I'm considering to just convert the HSTORE columns into arrays in my queries but is there a way to avoid such conversions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`libpqtypes`](http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/) appears to have some support for `hstore`.

Another option is to avoid directly interacting with `hstore` in your code. You can still benefit from it in the database without dealing with its text representation on the client side. Say you want to fetch a hstore field; you just use:

```
SELECT t.id, k, v FROM thetable t, LATERAL each(t.hstorefield);
```

or on old PostgreSQL versions you can use the quirky and nonstandard set-returning-function-in-SELECT form:

```
SELECT t.id, each(t.hstorefield) FROM thetable t;
```

(but watch out if selecting multiple records from `t` this way, you'll get weird results wheras `LATERAL` will be fine).

Another option is to use `hstore_to_array` or `hstore_to_matrix` when querying, if you're comfortable dealing with PostgreSQL array representation.

To create hstore values you can use the hstore constructors that take arrays. Those arrays can in turn be created with `array_agg` over a `VALUES` clause if you don't want to deal with PostgreSQL's array representation in your code.

All this mess should go away in future, as PostgreSQL 9.4 is likely to have much better interoperation between hstore and json types, allowing you to just use the json representation when interacting with hstore.

Comment: Thanks! There's a small error in your examples I think. It should be `each` instead of `hstore_each` (at least in 9.3). I measured this and at least in my case the array conversions provide significantly better performance.

Comment: @Muton Thanks, corrected. I always muddle it with `json_each`.

Answer (score 0):

The binary protocol for `hstore` is not complicated.
See the `_send` and `_recv` functions from [its IO code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/contrib/hstore/hstore_io.c).
Of course, that means requesting (or binding) it in [*binary* format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-SELECT-INFO) in `libpq`.
(see the `paramFormats[]` and `resultFormat` arguments to `PQexecParams`)