# Postgres SQL parsing error when executing sql via PQsendQuery from C++ code - SQLState: 42601 message: syntax error at or near ""

Tags: c++, postgresql-9.5

I have the below table on Postgres 9.5 database:

```
\d t_rstats
               Table "public.t_rstats"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 eid       | bigint  |           | not null |
 timestamp | integer |           | not null |
 mids      | hstore  |           |          |
```

I am trying to execute the below SQL command from C++ using [PQsendQuery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/libpq-async.html) of libpq Library/API.

```
SELECT eid, timestamp, mids->'1144' AS m1144 FROM t_rstats
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1608638528 AND 1608638618
AND eid IN (3568,3600,4088,4120,4608,4640,5128,5160,5648,5680,6584)
ORDER BY eid, timestamp
```

For reference, a portion of C++ code that prepared the above SQL

```
std::vector<unsigned> metric_ids;
string selected_fields("SELECT eid,timestamp");
for (auto itor = metric_ids.begin();
     itor != metric_ids.end();
     ++itor)
{
    selected_fields += selected_fields.AppendFmt(",mids->'%u' AS m%u", *itor, *itor);
}
```

I get an error with SQLState: 42601 messages: syntax error at or near "

I understand it's due to a single quote in the select query. Please note that the above query successfully executes when I run on psql command line interface.

I have tried to escape the single quote with another single quote as below SQL

```
SELECT eid, timestamp, mids->''1144'' AS m1144 FROM t_rstats
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1608638528 AND 1608638618
AND eid IN (3568,3600,4088,4120,4608,4640,5128,5160,5648,5680,6584)
ORDER BY eid, timestamp
```

Even the above one fails with SQLState: 42601 messages: syntax error at or near "1144"

I'm a bit clueless about this error.

Also, I have tried using the below query method without any success. On the psql command line, it works but when executed using PQsendQuery, I get an error with SQLState: 42601 messages: syntax error at or near "

```
SELECT eid, timestamp, mids->1144::TEXT AS m1144 FROM t_rstats
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1608638528 AND 1608638618
AND eid IN (3568,3600,4088,4120,4608,4640,5128,5160,5648,5680,6584)
ORDER BY eid, timestamp
```

Comment: Answers do not belong in questions. If you know how to answer your own question, do just that. Since you already added the answer to the question, edit it to remove the answer, and post your own answer. Self-answering questions is fine!

Comment: Thank u and will do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The library libpq that provides API for C/C++ applications to execute SQLs on Postgres DB may not support hstore (hash table) extension. However, I am able to insert into this table and populate the hstore column using INSERT SQL executed using libpq. Hope one with command over libpq confirms if my select query is not supported by libpq API.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537431/how-to-access-a-hstore-column-using-postgresql-c-library-libpq) very useful. Based on the answer, I have reframed the SQL query as below and it works when I execute using PQsendQuery of libpq Library. But the result would be in the narrow format when I select more than one key from the hstore column i.e., mids.

```
select eid, timestamp, key, value 
FROM (
  SELECT t.eid, t.timestamp, key::INT, value FROM t_rstats t, LATERAL each(t.mids)
  WHERE t.timestamp BETWEEN 1608638528 AND 1608638618
  AND t.eid IN (3568,3600,4088,4120,4608,4640,5128,5160,5648,5680,6584) ) x
WHERE key = 1144
ORDER BY eid, timestamp, key;
```